# How to make overflow elements not increase height of flexbox?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, flexbox, overflow

I want to build overflow: scroll in flexbox.

I don't know how to link an image in my google drive, so I link this URL.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=17uM5twoprxmbo5xQ37kgeTaMwn7FGSu_

You can see the overflow component increased its container height.
 The overflow: scorll component in flexbox works fine but it makes container height increased.

How can i prevent this issue.

this is bootstrap code.

```html
<div class="row display-flex">
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0; max-width: 35rem; height: auto">
    <b-img fluid" src="image" />
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="max-width: 18rem;  background: white;">
   <ul style="list-style: none; margin:0; padding:0;">
     <li><b-img :src="post.owner.thumbnail" rounded="circle" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" /></li>
     <li>{{ post.owner.username }}</li>
            <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="comment asd" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
       ........
```

```css
.row.display-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
.display-flex .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: For info . you can use `d-flex` class for `display:flex;` and `flex-column` for `flex-direction:column;` and then then flex-wrap for `flex-wrap:wrap;`

Answer (score -1):

You can use boostrap class for this :

- `d-flex` equals  `display:flex`
- `flex-wrap` equals `flex-wrap:wrap`
- `flex-column` equals `flex-direction:column`
- `col` alike `flex-grow:1`
- `h-100` equals `height:100%`
- `overflow-auto` equals `overflow:auto`

many more by the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/borders/

possible example from your code of the use of those classes

```css
/* demo purpose for snippet */

.fluid {max-height:90vh;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row d-flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0; max-width: 35rem; height: auto">
    <img class="fluid" src="http://dummyimage.com/445x555" />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col d-flex flex-column" style="max-width: 18rem;  background: white;">
   <ul style="list-style: none; margin:0; padding:0;">
     <li><b-img :src="post.owner.thumbnail" rounded="circle" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" /></li>
     <li>{{ post.owner.username }}</li>
            <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
   </ul>
   <div class="comment asd col h-100" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah ..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah ..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah ..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah ..blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    <p>blah..blah..blah..blah. .blah..blah..blah..blah..blah..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```